# error 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, http, azure-web-app-service

I am getting an error from the code below. **Error 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable** in my custom **DownloadFile** method.
My file is a zip file with two pdf. This code is breaking for that specific file only. I am having 55 files out of which only one file is giving me this error. File are getting uploaded/downloaded to/from Azure Website Directory.

See the property window below of that file:

[image]

This is my code:

```
try
{
  var packageId = updates[0];
  var packagePath = updates[1];
  var packageNameAvailable = Path.GetFileName(updates[1]);
  log.Info($"Package id {packageId} | {packageNameAvailable} is available to download. ");
  DownloadPackagePath = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", ApiConfigHelper.PackageRootDirectory, packageNameAvailable);
  var url = new Uri(updates[1]);
  **DownloadFile(url.OriginalString, DownloadPackagePath);** // problem here
  result = true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  log.Info("Error occurred while downloading package, stopping download. Cleaning up resources. ");
  log.Error($"Error:{ex.Message}", ex);
  log.Info("Cleaning up started....");
  result = false;
}
```

**DownloadFile Method:**

```
 private void DownloadFile(string sourceURL, string destinationPath)
    {
        long fileSize = 0;
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        bufferSize *= 1000;
        long existLen = 0;
        FileStream saveFileStream = null;
        Stream resStream = null;
        try
        {
            log.Info("Download started....");

            if (File.Exists(destinationPath))
            {
                FileInfo destinationFileInfo = new FileInfo(destinationPath);
                existLen = destinationFileInfo.Length;
                log.Info($"Resuming partial downloaded file from {existLen / 1024} kB started....");
            }

            if (existLen > 0)
            {
                saveFileStream = new FileStream(destinationPath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            }
            else
            {
                saveFileStream = new FileStream(destinationPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
                FileInfo destinationFileInfo = new FileInfo(destinationPath);
                log.Info($"Starting download FileName:{destinationFileInfo.Name} Size: {destinationFileInfo.Length / 1024} kB ....");
            }

            var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sourceURL);
            httpRequest.AddRange((int)existLen);
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
            resStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();
            fileSize = httpResponse.ContentLength;
            int byteSize;
            byte[] downBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            while ((byteSize = resStream.Read(downBuffer, 0, downBuffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                saveFileStream.Write(downBuffer, 0, byteSize);
            }
            log.Info("File downloaded successfully. Clean up started....");

        }
        catch 
        {
            throw;

        }
        finally
        {
            log.Info("Cleaning up unused streams....");
            if (saveFileStream != null)
            {
                saveFileStream.Close();
                saveFileStream.Dispose();

            }
            if (resStream != null)
            {
                resStream.Close();
                resStream.Dispose();
            }
            log.Info("DONE!!!");

        }
    }
```

Could you please help me identifying this.My log has an entry that says
**Resuming partial downloaded file from 2494 kB started....** And stuck to that only.

Answer (score 1):

> Resuming partial downloaded file from 2494 kB started

Based on the log information, the request range is start from 2494 * 1024(2553856). 2,553,856 byte is larger than the file size(2,492,548) which can be seen from the file property window. The range of file which you request is not exist that will cause 416(Requested Range Not Satisfiable)error.

The reason may be that there is a exist file. It has a same name as the zip file which you want to download. Try to delete the exist file in the same folder will fix this issue.